# Is there any way to automatically load column data types into SQLite using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a large csv file with nearly 100 columns with varying data types that I would like to load into a sqlite database using sqlalchemy. This will be an ongoing thing where I will periodicly load new data as a new table in the database. This seems like it should be trivial, but I cannot get anything to work.

All the solutions I've looked at so far have defined the columns explicitly when creating the tables.

Here is a minimal example (with far fewer columns) of what I have at the moment.

```py
from sqlalchemy import *
import pandas as pd

values_list = []
url = r"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amanthedorkknight/fifa18-all-player-statistics/master/2019/data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url,sep=",")   
df = df.to_dict()
metadata = MetaData()
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///" + r"C:\Users\...\example.db")
connection = engine.connect()
# I would like define just the primary key column and the others be automatically loaded...
t1 = Table('t1', metadata, Column('ID',Integer,primary_key=True))
metadata.create_all(engine)
stmt = insert(t1).values()
values_list.append(df)
results = connection.execute(stmt, values_list)
values_list = []
connection.close()
```

Comment: Can you include a small sample of the data? Is all the data of the same type (e.g. Integer, Float, String)?

Comment: The sample url above is a good representation of the different data types present in the actual data

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54844559/5320906) does something like what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions. After some time searching, a decent solution is using the sqlathanor package. There is a function called generate-model-from-csv which allows you to read in a csv (also available for dictionary, json, etc) and build a sqlalchemy model directly. It is imperfect on datatype recognition, but certainly will save you some time if you have a lot of columns.

https://sqlathanor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#generate-model-from-csv